# Key generation for symmetric algorithm

Tags: c#, encryption

I have simple symmetric encrypt/decrypt application that works fine:

```
namespace Crypto
{
    class Program
    {


        public static void EncryptSomeText()
        {
            string original ="My secretdata!";

            using (SymmetricAlgorithm symmetricAlgorithm =
            new AesManaged())
            {
                byte[] encrypted = Encrypt(symmetricAlgorithm, original);
                string roundtrip = Decrypt(symmetricAlgorithm, encrypted);

                // Displays: My secret data! 
                Console.WriteLine("Original:{ 0}", original);
                Console.WriteLine("RoundTrip:{ 0}", roundtrip);
            }
        }

        static byte[] Encrypt(SymmetricAlgorithm aesAlg, string plainText)
        {
            ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

            using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream csEncrypt =
                new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                    {
                        swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                    }
                    return msEncrypt.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }

        static string Decrypt(SymmetricAlgorithm aesAlg, byte[] cipherText)
        {
            ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

            using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
            {
                using (CryptoStream csDecrypt =
                new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                    {
                        return srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SymmetricAlgorithm sma =  SymmetricAlgorithm.Create();

            byte[] b = Encrypt(sma,"bla bla");
            string s=  Decrypt(sma, b);
            Console.WriteLine("Decrypted {0}", s);


        }
    }
}
```

I'm just wondering regarding key creation. Does it means that it is created in automatic way during symmetric algorithm creation? Is it generated each time different? I suppose, user should pass key for this purpose.

```
SymmetricAlgorithm sma =  SymmetricAlgorithm.Create();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Random key is generated when you access `Key` property of your `SymmetricAlgorithm`, assuming you did not set that `Key` before that to some predefined key. It's not generated during construction of `SymmetricAlgorithm` itself.

```
var sma =  SymmetricAlgorithm.Create();
// no key generated here yet
var key = sma.Key; // generated key
// accessing `Key` causes random key generation


var sma =  SymmetricAlgorithm.Create();
// no key here
sma.Key = myKey;
// you set the key, so no random key is generated
```

The same is true for `IV` (nonce) value.

Generating random key makes sense only once, then you have to share it between encrypting\decrypting party in some safe way and use it for future encryptions\decryptions. While you are there, note that `IV` value should be random for each encryption, so usually you just prepend that IV value to the encrypted binary array and before decrypting you cut that IV from the beginning of encrypted array and use for decryption.

Answer (score 0):

On this github [page](https://gist.github.com/twuni/5668121) there is utility class written in Java which performs encryption/decryption using symmetric algorithm, below could be one of encryption flows using symmetric algorithm :

- generate secret key using the selected algorithm (DES, 3DES, AES etc)
- generate secure random number of seed bytes which is computed with available the seed generation algorithm
- probably text message to be encrypted is not the multiples of 8 byte blocks that's why message must be padded with additional bytes to make the text message to be multiples of 8-byte blocks.(e.g. PKCS5Padding padding scheme )
- use random generated secure seed bytes as initialization vector as block cipher
- initialize cipher function with the symmetric key and block cipher
- finish encryption
- apply binary to text encoding with selected standard for initialization vector(IV) and encrypted binary data
- define message format before sending in order to split the message into IV and encrypted for decryption on recipient side